# mysql update column and remove text that starts and ends with string

Tags: mysql, database

I am new in Mysql and need some help on updating my column.
I have columns that have below values.

```
column 1
some text before 1
<script some text 1></script>
some text after 1

column 2
some text before 2
<script some text 2></script>
some text after 2
```

what I want is to update my column and remove that part of text that starts with .
The value between, before and after  is not same.

The out put should be:

```
column1
some text before1
some text after1

column2
some text before2
some text after2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to always remove the row that starts and ends with a `script` tag?

Comment: No, I want to just remove the text starts with <script and ends with </script> in c column and don't want to change other text in that column.